# Expanding frame title height in beamer

Tags: beamer

I am using `Madrid` style with the `dolphin` color theme -- I like the style of Madrid but I don't want the framing of the titles, which I get with `dolphin`. I want to expand the spacing of the frame title "box" (i.e., the space around frame title should be larger). I have the following MWE (I have a bit more there that eliminates the footer stuff that I decided to leave in just in case) and I tried using `height` as an option to `\usetheme` but it did not work. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Many thanks.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=149,10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \hfill%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
    \setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[framenumber]%
    \usebeamertemplate*{page number in head/foot}\kern1em\vskip2pt%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]
        \frametitle{This is a test}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did find an answer elsewhere on stack exchange ([Expanding frame title height in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550152/expanding-frame-title-height-in-beamer)) -- including it here for completeness. You define your own `frametitle` and you play around with `ht` and `dp` gives you what you want.

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=4.0ex,dp=1ex]{frametitle}
        \hspace*{1ex}\insertframetitle%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
```

Comment: Anecdote: I had to manually add positive and negative `\vspace` commands to get this to behave with the singapore theme; I also wasn't able to control the box height arbitrarily: it had a minimum size. I'm not sure how general this is since the beamer template I'm using is complicated and I haven't made time to reduce this to a minimal working example.